# sql server management console doesn't work with multi-byte characters

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to work out how to use SQL server management studio properly with multi-byte unicode characters. even something as simple as:

```
select N'动漫'
```

just returns square boxes in the result pane. I know the underlying database is set up correctly to handle unicode and other apps on the PC work fine with chinese characters

any clues very much appreciated

Comment: I used to get that in SQL Server 2005 in "Results to Grid" but not "Results to Text" I never bothered investigating it and just switched to Text. I don't get this issue on my current development machine (2008). Are you on 2005? Do you get the same behaviour? Are the default fonts different between the 2 output formats?

Comment: What version of SQL are you on? Have you checked Tools/Options/Fonts and Colors?   Some fonts may not be able to display unicode characters directly. I just tried it here on SQL Server 2008, default settings, results are fine.

Answer (score 8):

Changing the font to Arial Unicode MS did the trick for me.

I don't understand *why* Text Results displays fine with Fonts where Grid Results does NOT, and why other Unicode Fonts don't work but oh well.

Comment: that works only if you have Office installed... or some other product that installed it.  the font doesn't seem to be freely available

Answer (score 5):

After many frustrating hours with this problem, I just discovered a solution (if not an explanation).

Changing the Query Results font had no effect on my system (Win 7 Enterprise, 64-bit).

After much Googling I discovered this: [My Chinese Word Suddenly Appear As Square Box](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-7/my-chinese-word-suddenly-appear-as-square-box/698.html)

In short: create a new Windows user account, then log in as that user - you should find that your Chinese characters display correctly. Now log in to your original account, and you should find this also now displays Chinese characters correctly.

So creating the new account has the effect of fixing the behaviour for both (possibly all?) accounts. Now - anyone have an explanation?