# Korean (and other Unicode) characters in SQL Server 2008 R2 not displaying correctly in query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, unicode, collation, cjk

I have a database which needs to hold data in a variety of languages and alphabets. I am using the default Latin collation, but all the text fields are of the Unicode variety (nchar, nvarchar).

I can happily insert and retrieve Unicode data from the database using my front-end application, but if I view the data using SSMS then all I see is gibberish!

I can insert this:

```
극단적으로
```

Which then looks like this in SSMS:

```
ê·¹ë‹¨ì ìœ¼ë¡œ
```

But is retrieved by my front end application as this:

```
극단적으로
```

Now clearly the data itself is being stored ok, but why does SSMS display it as gibberish? Interestingly if I use SSMS to edit the data directly and paste in the above it then displays it as this (**EDIT:** it turns out switching the results from [grid to text](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/b8b52b86-7dc9-4e59-9a54-9b826ca8e710) aleviates this part of my problem as the proper text is displayed instead of the boxes.):

```
□□□□□
```

But if I copy and paste that into a text editor it comes out as:

```
극단적으로
```

In an attempt to see if this was just SSMS misbehaving (/misconfigured by me) I used MS Access and linked it to my SQL Server Database, but it displays the same gibberish as SQL Server.

This database will hold all the static text for a web application, so it is important for me to be able to view and edit the data easily, not easily done when all you can see is this:

```
ê·¹ë‹¨ì ìœ¼ë¡œ
```

Any suggestions would be great, I am really stuck on this.

**EDIT**

This is an example of my data insertions, which I have done in PHP at the moment:

```
$con = sqlsrv_connect("(local)", array("Database" => "myDatabase"));
$SQL = "INSERT INTO TableName (col1,col2) VALUES (N'극단적으로',N'극단적으로')";
sqlsrv_query($con,$SQL);
```

And this is an example of my data retrieval:

```
$SQL = "SELECT col1,col2 FROM TableName";
$rs = sqlsrv_query($con,$SQL);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo $row["col1"]." ".$row["col2"]."\n";
}
```

This results in this being output by PHP:

```
극단적으로 극단적으로
```

But the data is displayed as gibberish in the output window of SSMS if I run a select on that table.

Comment: Perhaps add an example of how you store and retrieve the data in the client?

Comment: @Andomar Just using SQL queries in php, but running the queries directly in SSMS has the same effect, except that on the `SELECT`'s you get gibberish in SSMS and proper output in php. I am not sure it will help but i will add an example in a sec.

Comment: If you make the same mistake during encoding and decoding, the two can cancel out.  But SQL Server would only see the wrongly encoded version.

Comment: @Andomar so how would i go about fixing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I could see no resolution to the problem, I've just started encountering the same problem in SSMS. I don't believe that the issue is with the PHP encoding, based on the edit regarding that if the results are viewed as text instead of grid then the problem is resolved (I experience the same behavior). I think that the issue is actually in SSMS and the encoding of the grid output, given that even SSMS can correctly display the Korean characters when viewed as text.

I've managed to fix the issue in SSMS by changing the font to "Arial Unicode MS". However I have noticed that the issue has occured in other applications as well particularly text editor such as Notepad++ and Notepad.

The following post seems to contain a more permanent fix for the issue (however I am on a network computer without sufficient privileges to verify it).

[sql server management console doesn't work with multi-byte characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174399/sql-server-management-console-doesnt-work-with-multi-byte-characters)

Note: I have been using Korean/Hangul data in SQL Server for the past 6 weeks without encountering this issue. It has only just occurred today, I have had windows updates but no other reason for the change in behavior. I have also used this viewed/queried this data previously with no issues on tables that have not been updated and are definitely encoded to NVARCHAR. My Korean colleagues can still view the data correctly in the Grid output in SSMS.

I hope this helps anyone else who stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 5):

So it looks like you have a string literal in a PHP file:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO TableName (col1,col2) VALUES (N'극단적으로',N'극단적으로')";
```

Have a look at [this post](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-query.php#105843):

---

Here are some things you might need to know:

1. Install mssql support for Debian (Lenny/Squeeze):

   ```
   apt-get install php5-sybase
   ```
2. When you got this error message:
   "Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier."

   In /etc/freetds/freetds.conf add these two lines (last two):

   ```
   [global]
   ;tds version = 4.2
   tds version = 8.0
   client charset = UTF-8
   ```

   You can edit "charset" in php.ini too (but you don't need if you did it previously in freetds.conf):

   ```
   ; Specify client character set..
   ; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.comf is used
   ; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
   mssql.charset = "UTF-8"
   ```
3. Use nchar/nvarchar/ntext column types if you need unicode support.

Comment: sorry i should have said i am using a windows 7 machine

Comment: @Ben: freetds.conf should still be somewhere, either in C:\ or in the directory in the `FREETDS` environment variable.

Comment: i couldn't find feetds.conf so i just edited the php.ini file, but i hasn't made any difference unfortunately

Comment: @Ben: OK, looks like you're using the [Microsoft driver for PHP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296182(v=sql.105)).  Perhaps double-check the encoding your file is stored in?  How does the Korean look when you open the .php file in Notepad?

Comment: That is correct, i am using the Microsoft driver for PHP. The files encoding is set to UTF-8 and when opened in notepad it displays the korean characters as the funny little boxes.

Comment: From this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/08/29/unicode-support-and-endianness.aspx), try to convert the SQL statement with `iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2le", $sql)` ?

Comment: Just tried that and it converts the SQL statements from `INSERT INTO` to `I N S E R T  I N T O` with a load of extra spaces ;-)

Comment: @Ben: UCS2 takes two bytes for each character so that might not be incorrect.  Does SQL Server accept it?

Comment: it might do if i were to programatically remove all the extra spaces, but it doesn't work with them in there.

Answer (score 1):

`ê·¹ë‹¨ì ìœ¼ë¡œ` is your `극단적으로` displayed in Windows Latin 1. So I guess SSMS is not configured to display UTF-8...

Comment: SQL Server can't store UTF-8.  An `nvarchar` column is UCS-2, and a `char` column is a single byte encoding.  So the driver has to convert UTF-8 to UCS-2 before it transmits it to SQL Server.

Comment: I don't do MS SQL so I'll trust you on that. What is sure is that `ê·¹ë‹¨ì ìœ¼ë¡œ` is `극단적으로` in UTF-8 displayed as Windows Latin 1. So the bytes stored are a series of UTF-8 codepoints, misinterpreted.

Comment: @Andomar so somehow i need to tell SSMS to stop trying to display these columns as Latin1.....

Comment: Something like that yeah. See also @Andomar's comment about UTF8 and UCS2 in SQL Server. You might have to convert the strings.

Comment: @Ben: SSMS and SQL Server only support UCS-2.  You have to instruct your driver to transmit the string as UCS-2 (or UTF-16, which is roughly compatible.)

Comment: @Andomar oh my, i have no idea how to instruct the driver to do anything! i changed the encoding of the php file to UTF-16 which resulted in the console output all being in chinese, but made no difference to what is being displayed in SSMS