# SQL Server Management Studio Hiding Some Characters?

Tags: sql, unicode, ssms, utf

It appears that SQL server management studio will not display some unicode characters in the text editor, although they are still there, but 'hidden' (if that makes sense - see example screenshot).

Does anyone know how to force the text editor to display these characters?

[image]

Edit - this is using sql server 2012 / ssms 11

Comment: Perhaps changing the font used by the editor could help, as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174399/sql-server-management-console-doesnt-work-with-multi-byte-characters?

Comment: Hi JoelC, thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try and unfortunately it didn't work.