# SQL Encoding Does Not Recognise Cyrillic

Tags: sql-server, ssms, file-encodings

Ok I have 2 machines. When I open `SSMS` and write queries in `sql` file `cyrillic` works. When I transfer the same sql file to `another` machine the `cyrillic` looks like "`Âàëåðè`". If this problem is related to `encoding`, how to configure `encoding` on both machines to be the same ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Is the problem occurring in the .sql files you're opening with SSMS, or is it occurring in the results windows you're getting in SSMS?  Are both instances of SSMS connecting to the same database?

Comment: The problem is in .sql files. When I open the file in notepad++ there is no problem. When I open the file with visual studio or SSMS cyrillic looks like Âàëåðè

Comment: I want to mention that I am using TFS to transfer files.

Comment: Does Notepad++ show the correct file content on both systems?  Is one system dropping the byte order mark?  If it was a problem in the results pane in SSMS, I'd say it was the [font settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174399/sql-server-management-console-doesnt-work-with-multi-byte-characters) but if it's the query entry window then I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look (in SSMS) under Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings and look to see if there are differences there? If the machines have different options enabled this won't help you as that's a Windows setting, but you can change the SQL setting here to use the Windows setting, choose Same as Microsoft Windows. I'm looking at this in SQL 2014 but I'm fairly sure it's in the same place going back a few editions...

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your file to UNICODE:

"Save as" -> Save with Encoding -> Unicode 1200

[image]